# Homemade cat toys

Tags: cats, toys

Homemade cat toys ideas? I have made many but now my cat wont play with them anymore:

- String and stick
- cardboard with holes
- ball of paper
- ring of paper

Comment: Hello and welcome to Pets.se! Unfortunately I don't think your question can be answered on this site. This isn't a forum, and we expect there to be a correct answer. As it is, there are no right or wrong answers to this question.

Comment: If it's a matter of wanting to get your cat interested in its toys again, you could edit your question to ask that. We've had a question on [getting a dachshund interested in toys again](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/how-do-i-get-my-dachshund-to-be-interested-in-toys).

Comment: it's very likely your cat just doesn't care about toys as it matures. Otherwise, try catnip, laser pointers, zipties, thick rope/shoelaces.

Comment: This doesn't concern health or something related to health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes, crates, really heavy duty twine (that cannot be chewed off, as that is a VERY bad situation), things that make crinkly sounds (balls of paper).  All get some interest from my cats.

If your cat is older, and ESPECIALLY if your cat can go outside, it may loose interest in "fake" toys.  Cats that spend some time outside are highly likely to loose interest in toys as they have more fun stuff to play with (live prey, which toys are usually some simulation of).

If your cat spends time outside I'd give up trying to interest it with toys.  It's kind of like having imaginary friends if you have real ones... why bother.